# What IP addresses are included in a subnet "range"?

Tags: ip, subnet, ipv4, cidr, mask

I'd like some help understanding subnets (CIDR).

I'm using [a tool](https://tools.tracemyip.org/IPv4-check-if-ip-is-in-subnet/) to check if an IP is in an acceptable range given a CIDR address. When I input an IP address (`12.245.105.190`) and check it against the same address with a subnet mask (`12.245.105.190/30`), any value less than 31 shows "`NOT IN SUBNET`" but gives a range that would seem to include the IP address:

```
** NOT IN SUBNET **
IPV4 ADDRESS        12.245.105.190
IPV4 NETWORK        12.245.105.190
IPV4 CIDR PREFIX    30
IPV4 RANGE START    12.245.105.188 <-- seems smaller than my IP
IPV4 RANGE END      12.245.105.193 <-- seems larger
```

Can you help me understand what I'm missing?

Comment: The tool looks like it's broken.

Comment: See the excellent answer to [this question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/7106/8499) for how to figure this.

Comment: That's over my head at the moment. Is the tool broken? I'm using a separate bit of code from a different source https://stackoverflow.com/a/14841828/378183 to validate an IP against a CIDR subnet and getting the same result.

Comment: You should take the time to understand IP addressing, and be able to validate it, before you attempt to do that for a business.

Comment: I thought my understanding of the theory was sound, but I began to doubt it when seeing the result from this (broken?) tool.

Comment: @IsaacLubow It seems to calculate the *start* and *end* addresses correctly but decide the *network* and *status* in some broken manner. Fwiw, it changes if you give it `12.245.105.188/30`.

Comment: Note that a network with a /30 prefix (aka 255.255.255.252 subnet mask) only has 4 available addresses, 2 for hosts and 2 for network and broadcast. That software identified incorrect start and end ranges. So for 12.245.105.x you can have up to 62 /30 subnets (255/4) meaning: Sub A = .0 to .3 Sub B = .4 to .7 Sub C = .8 to .11 etc etc. Until you reach the IPv4 address of .190 and then you can figure out which subnet you're in. (Assuming that whole network was in /30 but I highly doubt it, /30 is usually for peer to peer like router to router serial connections).

Comment: See: https://www.aelius.com/njh/subnet_sheet.html and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing#IPv4_CIDR_blocks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The subnet mask is a bit mask. The appended `/30` means the netmask spans the highest 30 bits (out of 32 bits):

```
       12 .       245 .       105 .       190 IPv4 address decimal
0000 1100 . 1111 0101 . 0110 1001 . 1011 1110 IPv4 address binary
1111 1111   1111 1111   1111 1111   1111 1100 netmask
0000 1100 . 1111 0101 . 0110 1001 . 1011 1100 network prefix
```

The 30 bits to the left are the network part/prefix.
The final two bits at the right side comprise the host part. This means the host portion (the two lowest bits) can be

- 0 0
- 0 1
- 1 0
- 1 1

Which are, when put together with the network prefix (first 30 bits from above)

```
0000 1100 . 1111 0101 . 0110 1001 . 1011 1100  
       12 .       245 .       105 .       188
0000 1100 . 1111 0101 . 0110 1001 . 1011 1101
       12 .       245 .       105 .       189
0000 1100 . 1111 0101 . 0110 1001 . 1011 1110
       12 .       245 .       105 .       190
0000 1100 . 1111 0101 . 0110 1001 . 1011 1111
       12 .       245 .       105 .       191
```

So there are four addresses on this subnetwork, where the first `00` and last `11` are reserved for the network and broadcast respectively. This means `.188`, `.189`, `.190`, and `.191` are part of the subnetwork, contrary to `.188` - `.193` claimed by the - seemingly broken - online tool.

---

See also [Wikipedia - Subnetwork - Internet Protocol version 4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork#Internet_Protocol_version_4) for more details on IPv4 subnetworks generally, and network prefixes particularly.

Comment: So - the tool is broken!

Comment: If you edit this answer to answer the question clearly I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: I was on the verge of deleting the question because it turns out the tool I was using is broken - but if you assert that that is the case and that my given IP address is indeed within the range the bitmask specifies, it may be helpful to others.